# IntPtr in cv::Mat constructor

Tags: opencv, computer-vision, c++-cli, opencv3.0, mat

How can I use `IntPtr` in constructor `cv::Mat`?

```
IntPtr ptr = bmp_Data->Scan0;
cv::Mat (640, 480, CV_8UC3, ptr);
```

But it does not work.

Comment: Can i ask you what type is bmp_Data ? You are using c++ but it looks like the bitmap class from .Net. Are you using c++/cli ?

Comment: Yes. It's c++/cli.

Answer (score 0):

You should probably use *the constructor*, not the assignment operator:

```
IntPtr ptr(bmp_Data->Scan0);
```

Answer (score 0):

1. Check that `ptr` is not nil
2. Bitmaps lines are often ordered bottom-to-up (default option in Windows bitmaps, positive height in BMPHEADER). In this case there is no continuous data block of 640x480x3 size, beginning at `bmp_Data->Scan0`, and access violation might occur.